# Find dictionary value in sentences and outputting sentence, key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to find if a word as values in a dictionary are found in a sentence (row of csv). And if the word is found in the sentence I would like the output to be ID, sentence, and key.

Running python 3.6 as a pandas dataframe. I can get the values, but cannot get the loop to work for `.items()` to get the key to be returned as well

```py
dict = {'housing': 'homeless',
           'housing2': 'homelessness',
           'housing3': 'evicted',
           'housing4': 'shelter'}

# dataframe with one row for each ID and sentence 
sentences = []
for row in text.itertuples():
    for sentence in row[2].split('.'):
        if sentence != '': 
            sentences.append((row[1], sentence))
sentence = pd.DataFrame(sentences, columns=['ID', 'sentence'])

#find dictionary value in sentences
def find_sdh(x):
    val = [x for k in dict.values() if k in x]
    if val:
        return val

# link sentence, id, value 
sentence['sdh'] = sentence['sentence'].apply(find_sdh)

# drop null values
df = sentence.dropna(subset=['sdh'])
```

This provides matched value of dictionary with ID and sentence.

```
(ID,sentence)
(246,'This is an example.')
(132,'This is a test.')  
(662,'This is fake data.')
```

I need the ID, sentence, and key (associated with the matched value)

```
(ID, sentence, key)
(246, This is an example., key1)
(132, This is a test., key5)
(662, This is fake data, key3)
```

Please and thank you!

Comment: It's hard to envision what the output of df is... some sample output of what you're getting, and then what you're expected output is, will help people understand how to advise.

Comment: edited with a sample of the df. I input two columns (ID, sentence) and output three columns (ID, sentence, key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add another method to assign to a second column:

```
def find_keys(x):
    result = [k for k, v in dict.items() if v in x]
    if result:  # not sure you need this
        return result

sentence['keys'] = sentence['sentence'].apply(find_keys)
```

Alternatively, you could assign a tuple of `(sentence, key)` to a new column with a different method, but this might be more difficult to work with. I'm not positive about the syntax here because I'm not positive about the structure of your data:

```
def find_stuff(x):
    result = [(x, k) for k, v in dict.items() if v in x]
    if result:  # again not sure you need this
        return result

sentence['stuff'] = sentence.sentence.apply(find_stuff)
```

About the `if result:` check, every function in Python has an implicit `return None` at the end. If your list comprehension doesn't assign anything to `result`, then `result` is just an empty array `[]`, which is not `None`, but both evaluate to `False` and often downstream code won't care about the difference. I'm not positive about the behavior with `.apply()`, but you might have the same outcome if you just drop the check entirely and always return your result. Worth checking because it makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Worked! not sure why I couldn't get my head around that